# Find query for MongoDB in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

I have the following query where the `oids` is an array of object id's.

```
users.find({ _id: { $in: oids } }, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

I expect a list of users where the id from the users are in the array of object id's, but the actual result looks like this:

`{ db: 
   { databaseName: 'users',
     serverConfig: 
      { _callBackStore: [Object],
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        options: [Object],
        internalMaster: true,
        connected: true,
        poolSize: 5,
        disableDriverBSONSizeCheck: false,
        slaveOk: undefined,
        _used: true,
        replicasetInstance: null,
        ssl: false,
        sslValidate: false,
        sslCA: null,
        sslCert: undefined,
        sslKey: undefined,
        sslPass: undefined,
        _readPreference: null,
        socketOptions: [Object],
        logger: [Object],
        eventHandlers: [Object],
        _serverState: 'connected',
        _state: [Object],
        recordQueryStats: false,
        db: [Circular],
        dbInstances: [Object],
        connectionPool: [Object],
        isMasterDoc: [Object] },
     options: { w: 1 },
     _applicationClosed: false,
     native_parser: undefined,
     bsonLib: 
      { Code: [Function: Code],
        Symbol: [Function: Symbol],
        BSON: [Object],
        DBRef: [Function: DBRef],
        Binary: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object],
        Long: [Object],
        Timestamp: [Object],
        Double: [Function: Double],
        MinKey: [Function: MinKey],
        MaxKey: [Function: MaxKey] },
     bson: {}
... and so on ...`

If I use `user.findOne(...)` the result is the expected user, but I like to query all users in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find() method returns you a cursor, so 'result' is printing all the cursor details. I guess you have to do something like:

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
     test.assertEquals(1, results.length);
});
```